# Several Docker Container Id originating from same docker image

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, commit, docker-machine

Why there is different container Id originating from the same Docker Image from the same command path as we can see in the picture?

1. What can be the specific case where I need several containers from the same images?
2. Do 'each' of these containers consume the equivalent size of the image?
3. I have noticed that the new container Id is listed once I reboot the system. What is the best approach to manage the scenario and run using the same container Id?
4. Does docker commit mean same as persistent volumes in docker? If no, how do they differ?

I couldn't find answers on stackoverflow. If the question is redundant please remove.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why there is different container Id originating from the same Docker Image from the same command path

To differentiate different running containers.

> What can be the specific case where I need several containers from the same images?

For example you want to run two sshd services - one on port 22 and other on port 23. Or any two same services.

Or there are two developers using one machine, and both are compiling their projects in a docker at the same time.

Etc.

> Do 'each' of these containers consume the equivalent size of the image?

The base layers share the disc space. Each container has its own private filesystem mounted "on top" other layers. They consume only the changes they made. They share the image on top they were built. You may want to research squashfs and https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/ .

Each processes inside containers have separate process space.

> What is the best approach to manage the scenario and run using the same container Id?

Use NAMES.

> Does docker commit mean same as persistent volumes in docker?

No.

> If no, how do they differ?

It creates a new docker layer, and commits that as a new docker image.

---

Image = tar.gz with the files.

Container = one instance of running image.

Comment: Also, Does the file and extra settings remain persistent without persistent volume for a particular container ID after system reboot, or "sudo docker start/stop 'CONTAINER ID' "?

Comment: `Does the file and extra settings remain persistent without persistent volume for a particular container ID after system reboot` Yes. It's like a separate PC, when you restart it it's still there.

Comment: Ahh, but again why would you prefer to attach separate data volume if a container has persistent memory? I guess, it's for sharing same data between containers?

Comment: Multiple reasons, yes, also for sharing same data between containers and between host and containers. But most importantly conceptually, to differentiate non-volatile constant service code between volatile state like database, configuration. Imagine you are running rdiffweb that uses sqlite3 database. If you put sqlite3 database inside the container, if you would want to _update_ rdiffweb, you would have to manually copy the database from inside the container. If you put it inside a volume, you can run any rdiffweb version (and any other program) using the same database.  Also backups.